# Api is working fine with postman but not working in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, axios

Nodejs api is working fine with postman but while i'm trying it with react i'm getting some errors like message: "Request aborted", name: "AxiosError", code: "ECONNABORTED"

I haven't added the authentication yet in my api so that is not needed i guess.

[image: Axios call from react]

[image: NODEJs api]
[image: Error]

I tried to send it in various ways even i tried to handle preflight problem of cors but not sure if i handled that or not! the api is working with postman absolutely ok response as expected.

Comment: the code appears to be running on `localhost:3000`? But your React code state port `5000`? Is the backend running on a different port? Or is the port number incorrect?

Comment: my react is running on port 3000 and backend is running on port 5000

Comment: It seems like your API gives a timeout due to you hitting the API URL on the wrong port.

Comment: @PareshBarad Can you please guide how should i progress to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you don't pass credentials  query params in you get request. if you have added credentials in your get request replace your http method with post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33434112)